# SHA1 returning hash of incorrect length in C++

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, sha

In below C++ code, SHA1 should return [20 length hash](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html) values.
Most of the times, `id` is of length 20 (which is correct). But sometimes it is 6 or 4. Not sure why. Please help.

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <limit.h>
#include <other common libraries>
    
void calc_id(char * ip, unsigned short port, unsigned char *id)
{
      char data[256];
      int len;
     
      //format print
      len = snprintf(data, 256,"%s%u", ip, port);
      cout<<"length is :: "<<len<<endl;
      cout<<"data is ::" << data<<endl;
    
      //id is just the SHA1 of the ip and port string
      SHA1((unsigned char *) data, len, (unsigned char *) id);
      cout << "SHA1 hash is :: " << id << endl;
      cout << "length of hash is" << lengthOfU(id) <<endl;
    
      return;
}

int lengthOfU(unsigned char * str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*(str++))
    {
        i++;
        if (i == INT_MAX) //INT_MAX from limit.h
            return -1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

ip is like `127.0.0.1`

port is like `6671`

I am trying to calculate a unique id for `ip port` pair. SHA1 hash will be some "special" characters but the length should come as 20.

Answer (score 3):

SHA1, like other hashes, is a *binary* sequence of bytes. Don't use `strlen` on it (and don't hand-write your own `strlen` either). If there is a `\0` in there you're going to get truncation; if there is *not* a `\0` in there you're going to start reading unallocated memory.

If you want it as a string, you need to convert it to hex; then it will have length 40.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We are using `strlen` many times to calculate length of hash and it is coming as 20 most of the times (as you said, we shouldn't do this). So how to calculate length of binary hash sequence? Should I use sizeof() function? As per requirement of the code, we should not convert it to hex.

Comment: @sam you don't *have* to calculate the length, it is *always* 20.

Comment: Ok. If we are printing it, is it showing only 4-5 "special" characters in some cases. While in many other cases,  it is showing 20 "special" characters. So, even if it shows 4-5 characters, the length would be 20?

Comment: @sam a SHA doesn't have *any* characters, only bytes. Don't try to print bytes to a text stream. If you want to print it, **convert to hex**

Answer (score 0):

Because the id is not a string it's a collection of 20 bytes and zero is a perfectly valid value for one of the bytes to have.

You will need to turn it into a hex string before calling **lengthOfU**

Comment: Thank you. But why zero would truncate the length of hash?

Comment: Because a strings length is calculated by checking each byte until you reach a null-terminator '\0' which has a numerical value of 0. SHA1() dose not return a string, it returns a collection of bytes.